# Cannot read property 'trainingName' of undefined

Tags: mongodb, angular, mean-stack

I am using Mean Stack with Angular 4 for application development. However, I am facing below error:

HTML Code:

```
<form #adminForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="insertSession(adminForm)">
    <h2 style="text-align: center"> Admin Form </h2>

    <div class="form-group row">
     <label for="trainingName" class="col-sm-2 form-col-label">Training Name</label>
     <div class="col-sm-6"> 
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="TrainingName"  [(ngModel)]="SessionDetails.trainingName" name="trainingName" #TrainingName="ngModel">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
     <label for="description" class="col-sm-2 form-col-label">Description</label>
     <div class="col-sm-6"> 
     <textarea class="form-control" id="Description" name="Description" placeholder="" description="description" [(ngModel)]="SessionDetails.description" #description="ngModel"></textarea>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="save" class="col-sm-2 form-col-label"></label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">

    <button class="btn btn-primary col-sm-2" id="Save" type="submit">Save</button>
      </div>
          </div>
      </form>
```

Typscript file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SessionDetails } from './SessionDetails';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-form',
  templateUrl: './admin-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-form.component.css']
})
export class AdminFormComponent implements OnInit {

   sessions : SessionDetails[];
   newSession :SessionDetails ;
  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    //console.log('into admin');
     this.newSession = SessionDetails.CreateDefault()
      }
insertSession(adminForm){
  console.log(adminForm.value);
  console.log('insertSession');
    this.dataService 
    .insertNewSession(this.newSession)
    .subscribe(
      data =>
      {
         this.sessions.push(this.newSession);
         console.log("Added user");

      }
    )
}

}
```

Error:

```
ng:///AppModule/AdminFormComponent.ngfactory.js:40 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'trainingName' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///AppModule/AdminFormComponent.ngfactory.js:239)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (vendor.bundle.js:63071)
    at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.bundle.js:62218)
    at callViewAction (vendor.bundle.js:62569)
    at execComponentViewsAction (vendor.bundle.js:62501)
    at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.bundle.js:62224)
    at callViewAction (vendor.bundle.js:62569)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (vendor.bundle.js:62527)
    at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.bundle.js:62219)
    at callViewAction (vendor.bundle.js:62569)
```

Not sure if the issue is due to binding. I am trying to insert entries from the html page to the Mongo db database.

Comment: It seems you created a custom directive. Could you post its code and the HTML calling it ?

Comment: I didn't see any variable of named by `SessionDetails`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to bind input with`SessionDetails` model (which is `undefined`) instead of binding with variable `newSession`.

Comment: SessionDetails is a model class and its p-arameters are being initialized to null using Createdefault() method

Comment: OK. But it's initialized to late and `ngModel` is failing to bind with `SessionDetails.trainingName`.

Comment: I tried implementing both the solution i.e. initializing SessionDetails within constructor and also tried using ngIf within the HTML code. But it is still giving same error. It is giving error at                                
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="TrainingName"  [(ngModel)]="SessionDetails.trainingName" name="trainingName" #TrainingName="ngModel">

Comment: Oh, I've misread part of your typescript code. You've tried to bind `ngModel` with `SessionDetails` model instead of binding with variable `newSession`. I`ll update my answer.

Comment: The error is removed if I use *ngIf="SessionDetails.trainingName" but this code removes the text area from my UI since it is not getting any value for trainingName property. Not sure How to fix this. I am new to this technology kindly help.

Comment: Look at my updated answer - you need to replace `[(ngModel)]="SessionDetails.trainingName"` with `[(ngModel)]="newSession.trainingName"`